# What is the correct REST Urlpattern for POST operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have rest url support POST request. its looks like

**api/country/{countryId}/state**

using to create **state** resource in a **country** with given id

but the mapping function of this url is

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int countryId,StateDto state)
    {
        var country = _countryAppService.AddNewState(state, countryId);
        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, country);
        return message;

    }
```

and expected sample of the given urls is like 
**api/country/1/state** (create a new state in country with id=1)

but here i am not using the  url value (1)  in the above function instead of here the caller need to pass the corresponding countryId via request body, ie there is no any guarantee to both contryId in url and post request are same. so my doubt is what is the right url pattern to save a state in particular country vai a post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass StateDto object in body also,it will go in body ,id can go in url

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]int countryId,[FromBody]StateDto state)
    {
        var country = _countryAppService.AddNewState(state, countryId);
        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, country);
        return message;

    }
```

Only one param can come from body , other have to come from uri, you can read more here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Passing stateDto in uri is also an option but then you will have to pass all its members in querystring.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same information in the resource path and the request body, it's duplication of information; the caller should never need to pass you the same information twice in the same request.

You should pick one as the authoritative source and ignore the other. Since you must have the correct resource address to perform the operation, I would suggest you need to take the value from there:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int countryId,StateDto state)
{
    // Compose the DTO from the route parameter.
    state.CountryId = countryId;

    var country = _countryAppService.AddNewState(state);
    var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, country);
    return message;
}
```